# How is a TSQL Join implemented internally when there is a many-to-single relationship?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

Apologies if this has been posted elsewhere; there are so many questions relating to joining on duplicates, I cannot find an answer.  Note that this question is **not asking how to remove duplicate rows in results**.

Take the following scenario, whereby two tables are joined using a text-match, but one of the tables contains a large number of duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), textval nvarchar(250));
INSERT INTO #test (textval) VALUES (N'Luke'),(N'Han'),(N'Vader');

DECLARE @tmp TABLE (textval nvarchar(250));
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES (N'Luke'),(N'Luke'),(N'Luke'),(N'Luke'),(N'Luke'),(N'Jabba');

-- Query 1
SELECT
    tmp.textval,
    t.ID
FROM
    @tmp tmp LEFT JOIN
    #test t ON tmp.textval = t.textval; 

DROP TABLE #test;
```

I get the desired output here...

[image: Correct result]

...but, is that an efficient way to perform this query?  Specifically, I am wondering whether TSQL will create a join on every instance of 'Luke' from the table variable, or **does it internally remove the duplicates, and therefore only look for 'Luke' once, instead of five times for the five instances**?

I tried to look at the statistics and execution plan, but don't know what figures would signify what is happening.

### UPDATE

As per Remus's answer, [here is the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1W6VsiVz) from the above query, showing zero rewinds/rebinds.

Here is a screen grab of the rewinds/rebinds figure:
[image: Can I get a rewiiiiiind?]

Comment: You can see exactly what will happen if you display the execution plan for the query. Without indexes though the only way the server can find multiple instances is by searching all rows - how can it know what is available and what not? Most likely thouth it will loop over the bigger table (according to the data's statistics) and look up entries in the smaller table. Add an index to `textval` to improve performance

Comment: It is just silly to think SQL would do a distinct and count before any join

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking and I'm dreadfully sorry it falls way short of your expectations.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about how is the Join implemented. There are three main strategies:

- [nested loops](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [hash](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189313(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [merge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190967(v=sql.105).aspx)

None of them will 'eliminate' the duplicates, since doing so would be semantically incorrect. However, both Hash and Merge join would 'visit' the value in the `#test` table only once, while Nested Loops *may* visit the value multiple times (once for each matching row in the `@tmp` table). I say *may* because it depends on which side (left `#test` or right `@tmp`) is chosen by SQL optimizer as the driver of the nested loop.

Comment: Great, thanks.  In the plan I see a Nested Loop, but not whether the join has been 'made' 5 times, or 1?  Perhaps the infomation is there but I'm missing it?  Would it be fair to say that my TSQL should try to *persuade* SQL to use Hash/Merge by filtering the duplicates before the join, in this particular case?

Comment: The operator that is the *child* of the nested loop will have a `Actual Rewinds` count. See https://www.scarydba.com/2011/06/15/rebind-and-rewind-in-execution-plans/

Comment: You can persuade a query join strategy using [join hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join). But is a slippery slope and you can easily shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: An interesting article, thank you.  Just for clarity, in my plan I see zero rebinds and zero rebinds.  The article doesn't mention zeros - so I assume that's a good thing then, that SQL just used a single value from the duplicates and took the most efficient approach?

Comment: Okay thanks.  The question has been updated with the required info.

Answer (score 2):

There are no Automatic Ways in which SQL Removes the Duplicates

If you want to Remove the Duplicates across all Columns, then You can simply use the `DISTINCT` Keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tmp.textval,
    t.ID
FROM
    @tmp tmp LEFT JOIN
    #test t ON tmp.textval = t.textval;
```

or if what you need to remove Duplicates based on some specific columns, then you can try either of `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK` functions.

Example

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tmp.textval ORDER BY t.ID),
    tmp.textval,
    t.ID
FROM
    @tmp tmp LEFT JOIN
    #test t ON tmp.textval = t.textval;
)
SELECT
*
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

But SQL Server *will automatically remove the duplicates* if you use a `UNION` operator and will Display the duplicates for `UNION ALL`